# Why Facebook Login does not work with my instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

When I try to login on my Instant App which use the Facebook Login for Android library, the login is stucked within the Facebook flow, I am not able to get back to the app. The login works when I use the full app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use an other deep link that the one you use for the verified app link which launch your instant app. One way to resolve the problem is to parameterize the app link (using the query string) to trigger the different behaviours you want.

Then, Facebook Login for Android which use a deep link to get back to the app will not work, you need to change the oauth redirect uri used by the SDK by going to the Facebook developer console > Facebook Login > Settings. A solution to resolve the problem for Instagram is to use the API Graph for Instagram which also use Facebook Login.